# How can I get a count in SQL query from a HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I want to echo the result of the SQL Query and use it later in a Javascript chart generator.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="interpret.php" method="get">


            Categorie
            <select class="textCategorie" name="categorie">

              <option value="DECEDATI">Decedati</option>
              <option value="RANITI">Raniti</option>
              <option value="DISPARUTI">Disparuti</option>
              <option value="CLADIRI_DISTRUSE">Cladiri distruse</option>
              <option value="DURATA">Durata</option>
              <option value="MAGNITUDINE">Magnitudine</option>
              <option value="ADANCIME">Adancime</option>
              <option value="PAGUBE">Pagube</option>
              <option value="NUMAR_REPLICI">Numar replici</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Tip:
            <input type="radio" name="greater" value=">"> > <br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaller" value="<"> < <br>

            Numar:
            <input type="number" name="numar" min=0></input>
            <br />
    <input type="reset"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
echo $_GET['categorie'];
if(isset($_GET['greater']))
        echo $_GET['greater'];
else 
    echo $_GET['smaller'];
echo $_GET['numar'];

$conn = oci_connect('student', 'STUDENT', 'localhost/XE');
    if( !$conn ) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error( htmlentities( $e['message'], ENT_QUOTES ), E_USER_ERROR );
    }

    $stid = oci_parse( $conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM nepal where ".$_GET['categorie']." ".$_GET['greater']." ".$_GET['numar']);
    if( !$stid ) {
        $e = oci_error( $conn );
        trigger_error( htmlentities( $e['message'], ENT_QUOTES ), E_USER_ERROR );
    }
    echo " ";
    echo oci_execute($stid);
```

JS code:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['<10 decedaţi', 19],
        ['între 10 şi 100 decedaţi', 6],
        ['între 100 şi 1000 decedaţi', 6],
        ['peste 1000 decedaţi', 3]                                           
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'DECEDAȚI ÎN NEPAL',
        is3D: true,
        colors:['green','#E8CF00','orange','red'],
        backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
        titleTextStyle: {
                fontSize: 22, 
                bold: true,     
          }

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

In JS are 4 partitions with the values of: 19, 6, 6, 4. Instead of that numbers I need to return from PHP SQL Queries.

Comment: Instead of echo you can make a `$.get ` and call that PHP file to get the query data.

Comment: run query and echo result of query instead of values? <?php echo $row['test'];?>